# configure host headers in xampp

Tags: php, iis-7, xampp

Im new to xampp and not sure if the following is possible, my server has sites running on iis using port `80`. XAMPP is configured to use `8887`. How can i configure hostheaders in xampp so `blog.name.com` for instance will use a wordpress site running on xampp instead of looking at iis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIS owns port 80 so you need to configure IIS for your blog.name.com  and add a webpage or other redirect to port 8887

From https://forums.iis.net/p/1189549/2022132.aspx#2022132 :

> Then you can add a new website to IIS with hostname app1.company.com
>   and bound to port 80. Now you have two choices, a) make a redirect to
>   the apache site with port 8080 or host a new HTML file on your IIS
>   where you make the rewrite by HTML.
>
> ```
> Code needed will look like this:
> ```
>
> (Place the following HTML redirect code between the  and  tags of your HTML code. )

```
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=http://app1.company.com:8080">
```

> The above HTML redirect code will redirect your visitors to another
>   web page instantly. The content="0; may be changed to the number of
>   seconds you want the browser to wait before redirecting.